# Recommended pattern for parent child relationship ownership

Tags: c++, design-patterns, shared-ptr

I am new to c++ and am trying to understand reference counted memory. In the code below I have 2 methods for returning the vector of rectangles

```
vector<RectangleRef> &rectanglesRef() { return rects_; }
vector<RectangleRef> rectangles() { return rects_; }
```

What i am unsure about is if either of them creates a new vector on the stack for the caller?

What is the recommend pattern when you have ClassA that contains many ClassB's in a vector that you want to be able to expose? Do you do

```
void addRectangle(RectangleRef r) { rects_.push_back(r); }
void removeRectangle(RectangleRef r);
vector<RectangleRef> rectangles() { return rects_; }
```

or do you just give callers access to the internal structure and allow them to add/remove things at will?

If the Rectangle class was to keep a back pointer to the Test class that it belongs to, is using

```
typedef std::weak_ptr<Test> TestWeakRef;
...
TestWeakRef test_;
```

the correct idiom?

Thanks for any help.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
    Point() {
        x_ = 0.0;
        y_ = 0.0;
    }

    Point(double x, double y) {
        x_ = x;
        y_ = y;
    }

    double x() const { return x_; }
    double y() const { return y_; }

    void setX(double x) { x_ = x; }
    void setY(double y) { y_ = y; }

    void offset(double dx, double dy) {
        setX(x() + dx);
        setY(y() + dy);
    }

    bool operator == (Point const &point) {
        return x() == point.x() && y() == point.y();
    }

    void operator = (Point const &point) {
        setX(point.x());
        setY(point.y());
    }

private:
    double x_;
    double y_;
};


class Size {
public:
    Size() {
        width_ = 0.0;
        height_ = 0.0;
    }

    Size(double width, double height) {
        width_ = width;
        height_ = height;
    }

    double width() const { return width_; }
    double height() const { return height_; }
    double area() const { return width() * height(); }

    void setWidth(double width) { width_ = width; }
    void setHeight(double height) { height_ = height; }

private:
    double width_, height_;
};

class Rectangle {
public:
    Rectangle() {
        origin_ = Point();
        size_ = Size();
    }

    Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        origin_ = Point(x, y);
        size_ = Size(width, height);
    }

    Point origin() const { return origin_; }
    Size size() const { return size_; }

private:
    Point origin_;
    Size size_;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Rectangle> RectangleRef;
typedef std::weak_ptr<Rectangle> RectangleWeakRef;

class Test {
private:
    vector<RectangleRef> rects_;

public:
    Test() {
        rects_ = vector<RectangleRef>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            RectangleRef ptr = make_shared<Rectangle>(i*1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            rects_.push_back(ptr);
        }
    }

    vector<RectangleRef> &rectanglesRef() { return rects_; }
    vector<RectangleRef> rectangles() { return rects_; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    vector<RectangleRef> r;
    vector<RectangleRef> r1;

    if (true) {
        Test t = Test();

        r = t.rectangles();
        r1 = t.rectanglesRef();

        if (r1 == r) { cout << "they match\n"; }
    }

    // insert code here...
    //std::cout << r->origin().x() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drew Dormann nicely answered the first few questions. I'm just adding a few things.

First, you should really only use `shared_ptr` if you actually need shared ownership semantics. Reference counting has overhead and if you do not correctly break up cyclic dependencies, it will cause memory leak, so you shouldn't do it unless you actually need it.

In this code, there's no real reason why you need to store a `vector<RectangleRef>` instead of a simple `vector<Rectangle>`. The latter also has the benefit of better data locality, which is important for caching.

Second, this

```
typedef std::weak_ptr<Test> TestWeakRef;
// ...
TestWeakRef test_;
```

is generally not a good idea, because it constrains the lifetime management policy of `Test`. That is, because a `weak_ptr` can *only* refer to an object whose lifetime is managed by a `shared_ptr`, you just made it impossible to do something like `Test t;` or `unique_ptr<Test> t;`. Do not do this unless you have a really, really good reason.

If you want back pointers, just use a simple non-owning raw pointer, which works regardless of whether the `Test` object is on the stack or managed by a `unique_ptr` or a `shared_ptr` or some other custom smart pointer:

```
Test * test_;
```

If the lifetime of `Rectangle`s stored in a `Test` can exceed the lifetime of the `Test` (which can only happen if you do not have exclusive ownership of them (e.g., storing `shared_ptr`s to them), which is usually unnecessary), your `Test` destructor may have to go through the `Rectangle`s it stores and clear out the pointer to prevent dangling pointers. But the typical case is that what is stored with a `Test` object will go away when the object is destroyed, in which case this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have a somewhat messy collection of several questions, but I will do my best.

---

*What i am unsure about is if either of them creates a new vector on the stack for the caller?*

This creates an entire new vector.

```
vector<RectangleRef> rectangles() { return rects_; }
```

This avoids the copy.

```
vector<RectangleRef> &rectanglesRef() { return rects_; }
```

---

*What is the recommend pattern when you have ClassA that contains many ClassB's in a vector that you want to be able to expose? Do you do ... or do you just give callers access to the internal structure and allow them to add/remove things at will?*

The common paradigm is to provide accessor functions, like you did.  I recommend that.

---

*If the Rectangle class was to keep a back pointer to the Test class that it belongs to, is using `std::weak_ptr` the correct idiom?*

It is a good approach, yes.

Comment: Since what's in the `vector` are actually `shared_ptr`s, returning a const reference (or by value) doesn't prevent modification of the underlying `Rectangle`s.

Comment: @T.C. Nice catch!  I completely missed that.